# MS Access: Combobox controlled records in form don't show up when combobox item is selected by button with vba

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a form:

[image]

where the all textboxes are connected to a source table. The combobox up top, **ConcreteItem**, controls which record is currently displayed in the form. The combobox works and all the data displays correctly but I also added a Next Item and Previous Item button for the combobox. I have this code for the combobox:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "ItemDescription = '" & Me.cbo_ConcreteItem.Value & "'"
If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    MsgBox "No such record"
Else
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If
rs.Close
```

This works perfectly. But I have this for the **Next Item** button.

```
Dim idx As Long
    idx = cbo_ConcreteItem.ListIndex

If idx <> cbo_ConcreteItem.ListCount - 1 Then
    cbo_ConcreteItem.Value = cbo_ConcreteItem.ItemData(cbo_ConcreteItem.ListIndex + 1)
Else
    cbo_ConcreteItem.Value = cbo_ConcreteItem.ItemData(0)
End If

Me.Refresh`
```

Unfortunately, when the combobox goes on to the next item, the combobox displays the correct selection but nothing changes below it. Even when I have a "refresh line" in the code, nothing changes. The only solution is to actually select from the combobox itself.

Can someone show me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try manually triggering the combo box event when you change the bookmark

add this line after setting the bookmark...

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "ItemDescription = '" & Me.cbo_ConcreteItem.Value & "'"
If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    MsgBox "No such record"
Else
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    cbo_ConcreteItem_Change
End If

rs.Close
```

Comment: Actually, I found a pretty easy solution of just copying and pasting the code on top to the code on the bottom. Both are part of different subs but the top sub can be used to update after the combobox was selected in the bottom sub. Thanks tho!

Comment: as long as you dont have the same code duplicated in more than one place, that will work... but when things change, you will wish that you had thought it thru more